# How to get the no_images/images through the nested map function

Tags: react-native

I want to get the images from the no_images using the nested map function.

I have try this but was unable to get the data

```
{this.state.safetyData.map((item, key)=>{
   return(     
     <View>
       {item.no_images.map((image,key) => {
         return(
           <View>
             <Text>{JSON.stringify(image.id)}</Text>
           </View>
         )}
       )}
     </View>
  )}
)}
```

The JSON data is:

```
[
  {
    "total_count": 12
  },
  {
    "no_images": [
      {
        "id": 23,
        "title": "Foundation",
        "title_phi": "pjilo",
        "description": "ok",
        "description_phi": "ok",
        "image": "1553413849ic_launcher.png",
        "type": "1",
        "image_path": "uploads/house_images",
        "created_at": "2019-03-24 07:50:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-28 08:51:58",
        "house_part_id": 21,
        "image_type": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "no_count": 1
  },
  {
    "percentage": 8
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `map` function you should check if the item `no_images` exists before using it. According to your `json` output there's other items in the map.

Just check for the object before using it like:

```
{this.state.safetyData.map((item, key) => {
   if (item.no_images) { // HERE: add this check
     return(     
       <View>
         {item.no_images.map((image,key) => {
           return(
             <View>
               <Text>{JSON.stringify(image.id)}</Text>
             </View>
           )}
         )}
       </View>
     )
   }
)}
```

Comment: i have try this code which you have suggested but it does not give any value

Comment: @RiteshRawal are you sure you have the `json` output in the object `this.state.safetyData` ?

Comment: I got the data when i use my first map loop but unable to get data when i use the second map loop

Comment: can you update your question with the console.log of `item`?